# How to add a UIView above the current UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have difficulty adding a subview (UIView) from within the viewDidLoad method of a UITableViewController

This works:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.progView];
```

But you can see the table cell lines bleed through the UIView progView.

I've tried this approach:

```
[self.view.superview insertSubview:self.progView aboveSubview:self.view];
```

Which is an attempt to add the progView, UIView to the superview, above the current view. When I try this, the UIView never appears.

-- UPDATE --

Following is the latest attempt:

```
UIView *myProgView = (UIView *)self.progView; //progView is a method that returns a UIView

[self.tableView insertSubview:myProgView aboveSubview:self.tableView]; 
[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:myProgView];
```

Result is the same as [self.view addSubview:self.progView]; The UIView appears but seemingly behind the Table.

Comment: Have you tried using `aboveSubview:self.view`? I'm not saying it would solve your problem, but it sounds like it would get rid of the error message you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. True that I lose the warning, but it still doesn't render the view. I will edit my post though.

Comment: a simple method is set frame of progVIew, and I am sure which can work. Any constraint will not work, including VFL

Answer (score 94):

I tried the approach above, but did not get it to work. I also found it to require too much configuration and code, since it requires setting up the table view from scratch (something that is easily done from within the storyboard).

Instead, I added the view that I wanted to add above my UITableView into the UITableViewController's UINavigationController's view, as such:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:<view to add above the table view>];
```

This approach requires that you have embedded the UITableViewController in a UINavigationController, but even if you do not want a navigation controller, you can still use this approach and just hide the navigation bar.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that when you do this, the view is also added over the navigation bar

Comment: You can do this: `[self.navigationController.view insertSubview:holderView belowSubview:self.navigationController.navigationBar];`

Comment: Another problem is that the added view stays on top of the UINavigationController, even after pushing a new UIViewController.

Comment: Over time, I have begun to move away from using table view controllers, except when the view should exclusively be a list and you want to enforce that. If you instead add a table view to a regular view controller and setup the data source and delegate yourself, you get a much more flexible setup, where the tableview is just another view in the main view, not the main view itself. This will free you from a lot of the built-in limitations of the table view controller.

Comment: @Raphael I figured it out using viewDidAppear, to make the view appear, and then on viewWillDisappear method, you can removeFromSuperView

Answer (score 42):

So 7 years have passed since my original answer, and I happen to stumble upon this problem again. Let's solve this properly once and for all:

1. In `viewDidLoad`, add your subview to the (table) view.
2. Pin the constraints relative to the safe area layout guide. This stops it from scrolling with the table contents (as pointed out in [cornr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47101036/1567836)).
3. In `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, bring the subview to the front. This ensures it doesn't get lost behind the table separators.

**Swift:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1.
    view.addSubview(mySubview)

    // 2. For example:
    mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mySubview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        mySubview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        mySubview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
        mySubview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // 3.
    view.bringSubviewToFront(mySubview)
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // 1.
    [self.view addSubview:self.mySubview];

    // 2.
    self.mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.mySubview.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100],
        [self.mySubview.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100],
        [self.mySubview.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor],
        [self.mySubview.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor]
    ]];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // 3.
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.mySubview];
}
```

Phew, glad that's done! Seeing how much saner this answer is, I'll omit my original answer.

Fun fact: 7 years on and I'm still an iOS developer.

Comment: I don't get how this can even work, when you do `- (UITableView*)tableView{
    return mainTableView;
}` and call after `mainTableView = self.tableView;` it's like doing `mainTableView = mainTableView`...

Comment: @AncAinu If you read the note I put in just below the code, you'll see that it's required to stop losing a reference to it. Don't see why that deserved a downvote.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeek because what you do is totally unusable. `- (UITableView*)tableView` this replace the original `self.tableView`, so when you call `mainTableView = self.tableView;` it's like calling `mainTableView = mainTableView` and because you never assign it before, it's like doing `nil = nil`. Your `mainTableView` is never filled with something in this code.

Comment: @AncAinu Fair enough, though if you spent time monitoring what UITableViewController does to its UIView and UITableView references, you'll find that it doesn't play by the rules. I've revised the answer, I hope it's helpful for you now.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeek `In your Storyboard or XIB file: Connect the tableView in the UITableViewController to the tableViewReference variable.` this changes everything. Cause I'm not using IB. I remove my downvote no problem

Comment: This works very well in ios 7 and 8, but I had a chance to try it in ios 6. In my case, viewDidLoad never got called, I think because "view" is never truly referenced. I changed - (UIView*)view { return viewReference; } to return [super view] if viewReference is nil and changed - (UITableView*)tableView { return tableViewReference; } to return [super tableView] if tableViewReference is nil. That caused viewDidLoad to get called, but the content of the view itself had "offset" problems. Any ideas?

Comment: For others that run into issue described in above comment, my solution was to add the new (UIView*)view method dynamically at runtime _after_ the viewReference code. The example here did the trick: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Comment: Has anyone managed to convert this code to swift? I was simply trying to override the tableView var get/set and same for view. It crashes (using ios 9)

Comment: Should the tableViewReference not be __weak to avoid retain loops? Any other IBOutlet connected like this prefixes __weak by itself. It doesn't crash.

Comment: @goggelj in setter methods set `super.view = newValue` and `super.tableView = newValue` and it'll work.

Comment: Excellent work. Remind me to buy you a beer the next time I see you, Thomas

Answer (score 12):

Ive been able to add a subview on top of a uitableviewcontroller by using uiviewcontroller containment.

UITableViewController is actually very handy when it comes to static cells and this is probably the only time where the common answer "just use uitableview" may actually not viable.

So this is how I do it.

1. give your **UITableViewController** a StoryBoard identifier i.e. **MyStaticTableView**
2. create a brand new **UIViewController** subclass and call it **UITableViewControllerContainer**
3. place this controller in place of your **UITableViewController** inside your storyboard
4. add a subview to the new controller and link it to an outlet called like "**view_container**"
5. on you **UITableViewControllerContainer** viewDidLoad method

add code like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UITableViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyStaticTableView"];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.view_container addSubview:vc.view];
}
```

Problems you may have:

1. if you have extra top space then be sure to add the flag "wants fullscreen" to your UITableViewController
2. if it doesn't resize properly on your UITableViewControllerContainer

add code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self.view_container.subviews lastObject] setFrame:self.view.frame];
}
```

at this point from your UITableViewController you can access you container view directly with

> self.view.superview.superview

and whatever you add to it will be show on top your table view controller

Comment: From iOS 6.0 and above, a UIContainerView makes solution this even easier.

Answer (score 12):

#### Swift 2018

Here is my way with storyboard:

1) Add a view in storyboard.
[image]

2) Link it with UITableViewController class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var copyrightLabel: UILabel!
```

3) Add it in code

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(copyrightView)
copyrightView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                            y: self.view.bounds.size.height - copyrightView.bounds.size.height,
                            width: self.view.bounds.size.width,
                            height: copyrightView.bounds.size.height)
```

4) Voilla!
[image]

The view will not scroll with the table view. It can be easy designable from the storyboard.

**NOTE:**
This solution adds subview to the navigation controller and if you are going to another screen from here further down the nav, you will find this subview to persist, remove it using copyrightView.removeFromSuperView on viewDidDisappear while performing segue.

Comment: Works great for me. Nice job.

Comment: Great work! It helped me. Just for others if you stumble across this: This solution adds subview to the navigation controller and if you are going to another screen from here further down the nav, you will find this subview to persist, remove it using copyrightView.removeFromSuperView on viewDidDisappear while performing segue.

Answer (score 11):

You can increase the zPosition of the layer of your view.

This will make it display above the other views (which have a zPosition equal to 0, by default)

```
self.progView.layer.zPosition++;
[self.view addSubview:self.progView];
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm just using a normal UIViewController that has a UITableView and I wanted to place a footer view that sat on top of the table view. For some reason, if I brought the foot viewer to the front via a `bringSubviewToFront` call or through the Storyboard, the UITableView would be pushed down. This left a big gap at the very top. I'm not sure why the UITableView can't have anything over it in the view hierarchy. Changing the `zPosition` property of the footer view's layer successfully brought it on top without changing the positioning of the UITableView.

Comment: This works but layers do not handle user interaction (thats why we have UIView). Just pointing that out.

Comment: It works just fine with my custom UIActivityIndicatorView! Being an indicator no user interaction is required, so it is perfect for my needs. I can finally show that the posters are stuck because they are loading. :)

Answer (score 8):

As UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, you need to add your desired view to its superview.

```
Swift:
self.view.superview?.addSubview(viewTobeAdded)

Objective C:
[self.view.superview addSubview: viewTobeAdded];
```

Comment: self.view.superview is nil for my UITableViewController (in viewDidLoad)

Comment: @Jovan: true but I still think Saikiran's answer minimalist answer is great. self.view.superview is not nil in viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews. Interestingly when you print out self.view.superview in the console it prints: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x157b03d70; frame = (0 0; 375 812); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x2834445c0>>. This UIViewControllerWrapperView name makes total sense.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `view` property of `UITableViewController` is identical to the `tableView` property. What this means is that the root view is *always* a table view controller, and anything added as a subview will be subject to the table view functionality. This has other undesirable side effects, like your subviews scrolling when you may not want them to.

There are a couple options here. You could override `loadView` and install your own view and table view:

```
// note: untested
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UITableView *tblView = [[UITableView alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectZero
        style:UITableViewStylePlain
    ];

    tblView.autoresizingMask =
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
    ;

    self.tableView = tblView;
    [self.view addSubview:tblView];
    [tblView release];
}
```

And then when you need to add a subview, add it below or above `self.tableView` as appropriate.

Another option is just to create a `UIViewController` subclass that does what you need. `UITableViewController` honestly doesn't add that much, and the little functionality it does implement is easily replicated. There are articles like [Recreating UITableViewController to increase code reuse](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html) that explain how to do this pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the help here. Unfortunately I'm really struggling to make your first suggestion work. Perhaps what I'm trying to do just isn't possible. At this point I'm trying to make a UIView the self.view of a UITableViewController subclass. And then make a UITableView a subview of the UIView. It doesn't seem like it would be possible to do this and I really need to convert my UITableViewController to a UIViewController per your second suggestions. Any ideas or pointers to tutorials or sample code that might be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't reference self.view to read from in loadView, you'll end up in an infinite loop.  Only assign to it.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem and got it solved using below code :

```
     [self.navigationController.view insertSubview:<subview> 
       belowSubview:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
```

This inserts view in correct place using controllers present in Stack.

Answer (score 5):

The Apple example "iPhoneCoreDataRecipes" is using a NIB to load a header onto a UITableView. 
See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Listings/Classes_RecipeDetailViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913-Classes_RecipeDetailViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_18):

Comment: I agree with this answer!

Answer (score 4):

I added a image above the the table. I used this code:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for swift (equivalent to Daniel Saidi):

If your controller is a UITableViewController in a Storyboard or XIB and you wish to reassign self.view to a standard UIView while preserving your existing table view:

```
@IBOutlet var tableViewReference: UITableView!
var viewReference: UIView!
```

Then in your implementation file:

Add these instance variables to your table view controller file:

```
override var tableView: UITableView! {
    get { return tableViewReference }
    set { super.tableView = newValue }
}

override var view: UIView! {
    get { return viewReference }
    set { super.view = newValue }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    //rewiring views due to add tableView as subview to superview
    viewReference = UIView.init(frame: tableViewReference.frame)
    viewReference.backgroundColor = tableViewReference.backgroundColor
    viewReference.autoresizingMask = tableViewReference.autoresizingMask
    viewReference.addSubview(tableViewReference)
}
```

In your Storyboard or XIB file: Connect the tableView in the UITableViewController to the tableViewReference variable.

Then you will be able to add child views as follows:

```
self.view.addSubView(someView)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update for iOS 11:**

It is now possible to add an Subview to `UITableView` when using AutoLayout constraints to the safe area. These Views will not scroll along the TableView.

This example places a view below the NavigationBar on top of the `UITableView` of a `UITableViewController`

```
[self.tableView addSubview:self.topBarView];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [self.topBarView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor],
    [self.topBarView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor],
    [self.topBarView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor],
    [self.topBarView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40.0]
]];
```

Comment: Could you explain what is `viewController` and what's the relation between it and the `UITableViewController`?

Comment: It should be the `UITableViewController` or rather its `tableView`. I copied the code from my UINavigationController subclass which has a reference to the displayed ViewController (which in my case IS the UITableViewController). I fixed the example.

Comment: This works well for positioning the subview.  However, I have found that tableView section headers are rendering on top of my view.  I will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

try: `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.progView];`

Or you can try to add `self.progView` to your table's view.

Comment: [self.view bringSubViewToFront:self.progView]; gives me the warning: 'UIView' may not respond to '-bringSubViewToFront:' and crashes the app with an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception.

Comment: so then your Controller is a UITableViewController?

Comment: Yes, my controller is a UITableViewController.

Comment: then replace self.view with yourTable

Comment: This seems to have the same result as [self.view addSubview:self.progView]; The UIView appears, but behind the table. Will update by post with this additional info and the current code I'm trying per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
[self.tableView addSubview:overlayView];
overlayView.layer.zPosition = self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply put the following code in viewDidAppear:

```
[self.tableView.superview addSubview:<your header view>];
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep UIView above table view in UITableViewController I'm using one(or more) of delegate methods (UITableViewDelegate).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.addSubview(headerView)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    tableView.addSubview(overlayView) // adds view always on top
}
// if using footers in table view
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) { ... }
```

As views can only have one superview that seams too be good solution, correct me if I'm wrong. Still getting 60fps so it's fine for me.

Comment: How did you layout `overlayView` and `headerVew`?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

This is the most simplified version of a number of answers here where we are recomposing the view hierarchy.  This approach does not require additional outlets for storyboards / nibs and will also work with programmatically constructed instances.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var strongTableView: UITableView?

    override var tableView: UITableView! {
        get {
            return strongTableView ?? super.tableView
        }
        set {
            strongTableView = newValue
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // theoretically we could use self.tableView = self.tableView but compiler will not let us assign a property to itself
        self.tableView = self.view as? UITableView
        self.view = UIView(frame: self.tableView!.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a customView above the current UITableViewController, it must be a nice way to use 'self.navigationController.view addSubview:customView' like Daniel commented.

However, in case of implementing customView that serves as navigationBar, Daniel's way can cause unexpected result to default or custom navigationBar on other navigationViewControllers that is in front and back of the UITableViewController.

The best simple way is just converting UITableViewController into UIViewController which has no limit on layout it's subviews. But, if you're struggling with massive, long legacy UITableViewController code, the story is totally different. We don't have any sec for converting.

In this case, you can simply highjack tableView of UITableViewController and solve this whole problem.

The most important thing we should know is UITableViewController's 'self.view.superview' is nil, and 'self.view' is UITableView itself.

First, highjack the UITableVIew.

```
UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
```

Then, replace 'self.view'(which is now UITableView) with a new UIView so that we can layout customViews with no-limitation.

```
UIView *newView = UIView.new;
newView.frame = tableView.frame;
self.view = newView;
```

Then, put UITableView we highjacked before on the new self.view.

```
[newView addSubview:tableView];
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
[tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
```

Now, we can do whatever we want on this brand new fancy 'self.view' on UITableViewController.

Bring a custom View, and just add as subView.

```
UIView *myNaviBar = UIView.new;
[myNaviBar setBackgroundColor:UIColor.cyanColor];
[self.view addSubview:myNaviBar];

myNaviBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[myNaviBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
[myNaviBar.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[myNaviBar.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[myNaviBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:90].active = YES;
```

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbP5R.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to add a loading indicator on top of my UITableViewController. To solve this, I added my UIView as a subview of the window. That solved the problem. This is how I did it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //get the app delegate
    XYAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //define the position of the rect based on the screen bounds
    CGRect loadingViewRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 50, 50);
    //create the custom view. The custom view is a property of the VIewController
    self.loadingView = [[XYLoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:loadingViewRect];
    //use the delegate's window object to add the custom view on top of the view controller
    [delegate.window addSubview: loadingView]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be reasons not to do this, but this works for me so far. If you use an ap

Inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you can run this, but make sure to only run it once obviously

```
self.searchTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.searchTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[self.view.superview addSubview:self.searchTableView];
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
self.view.superview?.addSubview(yourCustomView)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourCustomView)
```