# iOS: Add UIView to UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, ios5

I'm trying to add a `UIView` on top over the `UITableView` to mimic the iPhone Facebook style menu. I have it working fine by making the controller a `UIViewController` then adding a tableview however I am unable to make the menu a static menu unless the controller is a `UITableView`.

Is it possible to add a view ontop of a tableview and only make the tableview in the background scrollable without the view in the foreground scrolling?

Here is what I have with the subclass being `UIViewController`
[image]

But I am unable to make the tableview cells static via IB since it is not a subclass of `UITableView` Controller.

EDIT per NSJones Code:
It seems to be going somewhat in the right track. However the view still blocks the table. If I remove the view from the storyboard it will only display the table.
[image: xCode screenshot]

[image: iPhone Simulator Screenshot]

Comment: you can have a view in background and on top of that table view, with this handling will be easy, and might be you will achieve what you want.

Comment: When you say "on top" Do you mean like a header?

Comment: no..something like background is uiview and foreground is tableview.

Comment: I would like to do foreground is UIView and background is Tableview. I will edit my Question to show a screenshot of what I have with the UIViewController.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a UIView above the current UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641879/how-to-add-a-uiview-above-the-current-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a view hover the same way you make any real thing hover; Hold it up with something invisible.

Basically what you want to do is create a clear `UIView` (with user interaction disabled) that is the size of your view controller's view, and add it as a subview to your view controller's view property. That way it sits invisibly on top. then you can add a subview to that clear view and that subview won't move.

**Edit:**

It seems this nice clean approach won't work for you since you need your view controller to be a `UITableViewController`. The answer for this slightly more complex approach is to use a delegate method for `UIScrollView` which also works for `UITableView`. Apple has a fantastic demo of this concept in the `WWDC2011 - Session 125 - UITableView Changes, Tips, Tricks` video. If you can watch it I highly recommend it. The meat of this issue begins at about `36:10`.

But to sum it up you implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method. And handle the movement of the tableview by adjusting the position properties of the view. Here I am keeping an `UIView` property named `viewToKeepStill` still using this method.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    // CGFloat stillViewDesiredOriginY; declared ivar
    CGRect tableBounds = self.tableView.bounds; // gets content offset
    CGRect frameForStillView = self.viewToKeepStill.frame; 
    frameForStillView.origin.y = tableBounds.origin.y + stillViewDesiredOriginY; // offsets the rects y origin by the content offset
    self.viewToKeepStill.frame = frameForStillView; // set the frame to the new calculation
}
```

Comment: I did that however when the menu was open and I was scrolling the left menu it was also scrolling the right view with the menu.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think I know were your coming from now, if not drop a line.

Comment: Two things: With the delegate method approach the view you are trying to keep in a static location should be a direct subview of your tableview. Second, for your purposes you could probably replace "stillViewDesiredOriginY" with 0. But you'd have to test that.

Comment: Also I'm curious how you are creating your floating(fixed position) view.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding it as a subview of the table view, add it as a subview of the superview of the table view; that way it won't scroll.

So instead of this:

```
[tableView addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Do this:

```
[tableView.superview addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I did `[self.sideMenu.superview addSubview:self.contentView]` and it doesn't seem to show the main content.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want something that is visible full-time with the table, start with a view which contains both the menu view and the UITableView.  Make the table smaller so it ends where the menu view begins.  The table view can work with less vertical space.

Answer (score -1):

If you have your UIViewController's view to be your table view then your table is going to span over the whole screen, so you won't be able to add anything on top of it.

Why not try the following:

```
1) create a new UIViewController
2) add a view on top where you want your menu
3) in the space left under just drag a table view from the component library 
4) don't forget to set the 2 table view delegates to be your view controller class
```

that's about it?

Comment: I think you are missing the question. I already have a UIViewController with a tableview and it works fine. What I am trying to do is duplicate this with a UITableViewController so that I can create the static table menu via IB.

Comment: OK I didn't get you wanted a static table, the original text says "I am unable to make the menu a static menu"