# UIView appearing before navigation transition is over

Tags: uiview, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar, transition

I'm writing an iPhone app with a table inside a navigation controller. When the user clicks one of the cells in the main screen a UIView on top of the incoming view controller is created (it's like a toolbar).

```
self.toolbar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8823 green:0.8823 blue:0.8823 alpha:1.0]; 
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

The problem is that the view appears before the transition to the new view controller is complete and the effect is pretty weird. I suppose this is due to the fact I add the view to the navigationController,but I need to do this otherwise the bar would scroll together with the table and instead I want it to be fixed.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a possible solution: add the toolbar as TableHeaderView and follow [iOS: Add UIView to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265058/ios-add-uiview-to-uitableview)

Any other better solution is more than welcome