# XCode create a uiview on top of a uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I am having some problems and wondering if someone could help.

I have always used storyboards so I am rusty at programmatically creating UIViews.

Basically, I am loading data from an API and displaying it in a UITableView. The problem is, on one part of my app, the loading of the data takes at least 10 seconds as it loads 10 different things from the API. (This must use separate calls). I use a sleep of 1 second so as not to make too many calls to the API per second (Hence why it takes so long to load). This is integral to my app.

I have implemented a count which increments after each call. Now all I am hoping to do, is create a UIView with a label and progress bar to say that it is loading and how much. This must be displayed over the tableview.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: This seems to cover the same ground: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641879/how-to-add-a-uiview-above-the-current-uitableviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

1 - Create a UIView subclass, with outlets to all of the view's sub elements.

2 - Create a xib file. Change the class of the top view to the name of your UIView subclass. Add all the elements you want to the view and then hook up the outlets from the topmost view to the elements. File's Owner remains blank and unused.

3 - In the view controller that I want to use the view in I add:

```
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView"
                                                         owner:self
                                                       options:nil];
    MyCustomView *myCustomView = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can add the custom view to your table view. I would probably add a property in the view controller and assign the custom view to it so I could access the custom view using self.myCustomView.