# Common blur effect for top tool bar and navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, uiblureffect

I have many ViewControllers inside one NavigationController. In one of ViewControllers I should show toolBar below navigationBar. If simply add it to ViewController with necessary coordinates I have this:

[image]

But here is separator between NavigationBar and ToolBar.

If I set clear background and shadow images and set blur effect for navigationBar it is a problem with different blur effects in navigationBar and toolBar:
[image]
So is it resolution when there is no imagesShadow in navigationBar and there is common blur effect?

Comment: You can use `UIBlurEffect` class.

Comment: bro can you tell me that what are doing for navigation bar background color?

Comment: Exactly or if  you are using UIBlurEffect class   `blurEffectView.frame = self.navBar.bounds;` & `blurEffectView.frame = self.toolBar.bounds;`

Comment: As you see I use blurEffect. The only way to remove line separator is set background and shadow images as I said. If you do that you will see only Title and buttons from NavigationBar and you will see bottom layers.
So of course I am using blurEffect. Problem in this situation in two blurEffects. They are working separately and you see the border between bars. You may see is on second image. But in first image there is not such effects but bars are different elements on different layers.

Comment: bro have you tried this `self.navBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` & why you are using two different UIBlurEffect objects? & where are you setting that bgImage as a background?

Comment: @mukesh thank you for your attention but lest you understand the problem and look to documentation.

The default value is nil, which corresponds to the default shadow image. When non-nil, this property represents a custom shadow image to show instead of the default. For a custom shadow image to be shown, a custom background image must also be set with the setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method. If the default background image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless of the value of this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem. Idea of resolution make NavigationBar and ToolBar fully transparent. Next On every ViewController in place of bars and below them I put UIVisualEffectView with common height of bar or bars. So UIVisualEffectView simply should be the highest subview of rootView of ViewController. And here is a problem in case of using UITalbeViewController UITabBarController and so on. In my situation there was only UITalbeViewControllers. Firstly I try to use [this resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16249515/1416374). But I had problems with creating of multiple subviews wile navigation via different ViewControllers. Finaly I restructure storyboard. Every TableViewController I have replaced by ViewController with rootView simple view. TableView was subview of rootView. Also I put there VisualEffectView. I have done it for every TableViewControllers.
Here is a sample of structure:

[image: Sample of structure of controller]

I think there is there better resolution but currently this is optimal.