# How can i freeze UIView at the top?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, scroll, freeze

I have a UIView under the UITableView, so that the UIView will also scrolling down  when i scroll the tableview.

I have tried the move the UIView out of the UITableView but it is not allow, how can i keep the UIView at the top even when i scrolling the UITableView?

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: take a UIView as a superview and inside that add your tableview and description view as subviews.

```
Parent View
~> Add Desc View at top with 1:5 height ratio of Parent
~> Then add your tableview below desc view with 4:5 height ratio of Parent
```

You can vary that ratio to fit your need. 
So conclusion: put both your views in another uiview. So your parent view now has 2 subviews, 1 uiview and 1 tableview. That would allow the view to be at top as well as allow the tableview to scroll.

[Please Check This Image For Hierarchy Of UIViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44vr5.png)

Comment: but now i am using the Table View Controller instead of View Controller, i can not add uiView to table view controller, so... should i change Table View Controller to View Controller first? thanks.

Comment: yes thats correct....also check this, see if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641879/how-to-add-a-uiview-above-the-current-uitableviewcontroller