# Popup VC shows itself on a cell and not on the tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I display a popup from a function which runs on a button click, in a tableView (`FeedTableViewController`)

```swift
func preset(){
   let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostOptions") as! PostOptionsViewController
   self.addChild(popOverVC)
   popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
   self.tableView.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
   popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
 }
```

`PostOptionsViewController` is the VC which gets displayed on the tableView. Now when `preset()` is run, the `popOverVC` is being displayed on a **single-cell** of a tableView instead of the whole tableView.

I want to display it on the whole tableView. I followed the [answeres here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641879/how-to-add-a-uiview-above-the-current-uitableviewcontroller) and that's what I did.

But the VC is being displayed on the cell space and when you scroll, the VC goes with the cell. It takes the bounds of the cell.

So I tried to stop the scroll.

```swift
func scrollToggle(){
        print("CLCKED")
        if tableView.isScrollEnabled {
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }else{
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

I try to stop the scroll here so it looks like a popup. Now I can't seem to enable is back again from the action of a button in `PostOptionsViewController`

I try to do it like this from `PostOptionsViewController`

```swift
@objc func test(_ sender : UILabel){
   self.view.removeFromSuperview()
   let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
   let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "feed") as! FeedTableViewController
   nextViewController.scrollToggle()
}
```

But I get "CLCKED" printed in the console and the view gets removed but I can't scroll the tableView anymore

Comment: What is `self` on this line? `self.addChild(popOverVC)`?

Comment: The tableView? @Aaron

Comment: It feels to me like you're adding the VC instance to a cell and setting the size of its frame to the cell (if `self` is a reference to a Cell) and then adding the view of the ViewController to the table view's subviews. Hard to tell w/o more code, though.

Comment: This code is inside `class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {` @Aaron

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

```
self.tableView.addSubview
```

A table view is a scroll view. It scrolls its subviews. So the view you have added scrolls with the table view.

To prevent that,  pin the view to the table view’s frame layout guide. Or just use a presented view controller, not a child.

Comment: _To prevent that, pin the view to the table view’s frame layout guide. Or just use a presented view controller, not a child._ How can I do that?

Comment: _You mean bounds, not frame._ Changing them didn't make a difference here. Any idea why this is wrong?

Comment: No, I mean that how do you _pin the view to the table view’s frame layout guide_ or how do you _use a presented view controller, not a child_?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what details you want. There's lots of code and I can't put it all. It will be a mess

Comment: Ok so now we know this is a table view controller. So there is no other view to add to. I’ll correct my answer.

Comment: Okay so is the vc view supposed to cover the whole interface? Or what?

Comment: No, it will stretch then. I want to display it where the view is. But wants to stop scrolling. I'll update my question

Comment: I still don’t understand why you don’t just call `present` instead making this a child. You know, just like an alert. It prevents scrolling while it is presented, because the user can’t touch what is behind it.