# Can't add a UIView loaded from XIB as a subView of a ViewController view

Tags: swift, uiview, popup, uikit, xib

I want to implement a popup notification into my app when data was being updated successfully or not. To do that I:

1. created a .xib file: [Screenshot](https://cln.sh/HvEHiX)
2. created a class where I load that NIB:

   ```
     import UIKit

     class PopupView: UIView {

    static let instance = PopupView()

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var popupView: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var symbol: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PopupView", owner: self)
    popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
   }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

   func showPopup(title: String, message: String, symbol: UIImage, on viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.titleLabel.text = title
    self.descriptionLabel.text = message
    self.symbol.image = symbol

    guard let targetView = viewController.view else { return }

    backgroundView.frame = targetView.bounds
    targetView.addSubview(backgroundView)
   }
   ```
3. In the above class I created a `showPopup` method where defined a `backgroundView` frame to be equal to ViewController bounds.

When I call that method in desired ViewController I receive the behaviour where my `popupView` shows itself and then went off the screen straight away (black area in the GIF): [GIF](https://cln.sh/e4ukf4)

Would you be so kind to help me understand and fix the reason why the `popupView` went off the screen and not just equal to a ViewController bounds.

**The Code after Shawn Frank's answer**

PopupView class:

```
import UIKit

class PopupView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var popupView: UIVisualEffectView!
@IBOutlet weak var symbol: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    configure()
}

private func configure() {
    if let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PopupView", owner: self) {
        guard let view = views.first as? UIView else { return }
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
    }
}

func showPopup(title: String, message: String, symbol: UIImage, on viewController: UIViewController) {

    titleLabel.text = title
    descriptionLabel.text = message
    self.symbol.image = symbol
    
    popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    popupView.clipsToBounds = true
    viewController.view.addSubview(self)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
        self.popupView.center.y += 40
    } completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.popupView.center.y -= 80
        } completion: { _ in
            self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

Call in desired ViewController:

```
let width = CGFloat(10)
let midX = (self.view.frame.width - width) / 2.0
let frame = CGRect(x: midX, y: 0, width: width, height: 135)
let popup = PopupView(frame: frame)

popup.showPopup(title: "Test", message: "Tested super test", symbol: UIImage(named: "checkmark.circle.fill")!, on: self)
```

Constraints in xib: [Screenshot](https://cln.sh/it7hJE)

Current result: [GIF](https://cln.sh/gcj3vN)

Comment: Is the ViewController showing the popup a `UITableViewController`? If so, it's `self.view` is a `UITableView`. Adding view on `UITableView` might explain this behavior... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641879/how-to-add-a-uiview-above-the-current-uitableviewcontroller and all related question on "Add UIView on UITableView".

Comment: Hi, @Larme. Thank you for the reply. VC that is showing the popup is just a UIViewController...

Comment: Can you add code of view controller of how you initialize `PopupView` and how you call `showPopup` function

Comment: Hi @ShawnFrank! I initialise PopupView as a singleton inside class as static let instance = PopupView(). I added the code where I call this method from VC

Comment: Just debugging, what if you replaced `targetView.addSubview(backgroundView)` with `targetView.addSubview(instance)` -> any difference ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank, first it tells "@Static member 'instance' cannot be used on instance of type 'PopupView'" and if I fix it as targetView.addSubview(PopupView.instance) nothing happens

Comment: Ah yes, my fault, I missed the static. Can undo that and try another thing. Inside your init, comment this out `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PopupView", owner: self)`. Instead In your XIB. Maybe you have already done this but make the class of the View in XIB `PopupView` like step 6 here: https://medium.com/@umairhassanbaig/ios-swift-creating-a-custom-view-with-xib-ace878cd41c5

Comment: @ShawnFrank, Yes, tried that. Received a Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value on all outlets inside the view (titleLabel, popupView)

Comment: Then I feel maybe you did not connect outlets from XIB to View code ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank checked that and it's connected inside the popupView class. And even when I reconnect them I receive: fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

Comment: For that error, replace `fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")` inside `required init?(coder: NSCoder)` with `super.init(coder: coder) popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20`

Comment: @ShawnFrank tried that. it continues to fall with Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value (for textLabel.text inside showPopup()). Maybe its because I set constraints inside xib file? The goal was to create an animated popup view and design it in Storyboard (xib) and then implement to show for any VC I need... How would you do that if needed to create in xib or any other way with Storyboard? I need something like this: https://cln.sh/Rc7gKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use XIB and storyboard too much these days so I also had to refresh my memory and I used this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKV7kkxg1dE&t=652s&ab_channel=SwiftTutorials)

This is the custom PopupView class, I prefer not to use singleton for this but it is my personal preference

```
class PopupView: UIView {
    
    private let xibName = "PopupView"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var visualEffectBackground: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        if let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibName, owner: self),
           let popupView = views.first as? UIView {
            popupView.frame = bounds
            addSubview(popupView)
        }
    }
    
    func showPopup(title: String,
                   on viewController: UIViewController) {
    
        guard let targetView = viewController.view else { return }
        
        titleLabel.text = title
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
        clipsToBounds = true
        targetView.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

XIB is set up like this:

[image: XIB for custom UIView XCode iOS Swift]

Then in the view controller:

```
@IBAction func didTapPopUp(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // Give your own width, height etc
    let width = CGFloat(180)
    let midX = (view.frame.width - width) / 2.0
    let frame = CGRect(x: midX, y: 100, width: width, height: 80)
    
    let popup = PopupView(frame: frame)
    popup.showPopup(title: "Hello", on: self)
    
}
```

Gives me this result:

[image: Custom UIView from XIB swift iOS]

**Update based on artexhibit (OPs) comments**

The custom view can get its frames in 3 ways that I can think of:

1. Directly from XIB
2. By providing frame during programmatic initialization
3. From the frame set when creating the view in storyboard

To make the view work for all these scenarios, we should not do any frame adjustment inside the custom view and leave it to the parent / container / superview

So I made the following changes to work for all scenarios:

```
class PopupView: UIView {
    
    private static let xibName = "PopupView"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var visualEffectBackground: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configure()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }
    
    private func initializeWithNib() {
        
        var popupView = UIView()
        
        if let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(PopupView.xibName,
                                                owner: self),
           let view = views.first as? UIView {
            
            popupView = view
        }
        
        frame = popupView.bounds
        addSubview(popupView)
    }
    
    private func initializeWithFrame() {
        if let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(PopupView.xibName,
                                                owner: self),
           let popupView = views.first as? UIView {
            popupView.frame = bounds
            addSubview(popupView)
        }
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        
        if frame == .zero {
            initializeWithNib()
        }
        else {
            initializeWithFrame()
        }
        
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    func showPopup(title: String,
                   on viewController: UIViewController) {
    
        guard let targetView = viewController.view else { return }
        
        print(frame)
        
        titleLabel.text = title
        targetView.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

Now this has the flexibility to work with all 3 scenarios:

```
// In code
@IBAction func didTapPopUp(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // Default initializer
    let popup = PopupView()
    var originX = (view.frame.width - popup.frame.width) / 2.0
    popup.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: originX, y: 100)
    popup.showPopup(title: "Hello", on: self)
    
    // Frame initializer
    let popupWidth: CGFloat = 200
    let popupHeight: CGFloat = 100
    originX = (view.frame.width - popupWidth) / 2.0
    let originY = (view.frame.height - popupHeight) / 2.0
    
    let popupFrame = CGRect(x: originX,
                            y: originY,
                            width: popupWidth,
                            height: popupHeight)
    
    let popupTwo = PopupView(frame: popupFrame)
    popupTwo.showPopup(title: "Frames", on: self)
}
```

From storyboard
[image: Custom UIView XIB in storyboard XCode swift iOS]

This gives the following results

[image: Custom UIView from XIB initialize swift iOS]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and detailed reply! I have a question: you set the frame of a popupView in a desired VC, but what if I have standardised frame which I already set in my xib as fixed width and height? In your implementation there is no difference what I'll put in let width = CGFloat(200), it will use the number in constraint I set in xib. How to move away the size setting from VC to Popup class so I can initialize popup in VC as let popup = Popup()? I updated the code in main post (also add a view animation), add a screenshot of full constraints in my xib. Thank you so much!

Comment: @artexhibit - it is an interesting question. I think it will take width and height from XIB if you do not give it frame and then you can just adjust the `origin` or the `center` of the view but I think you will have to try it.

Comment: But in which method I should adjust the center? If I initialize the popup as let popup = Popup() in VC, it appears in the top left corner of the screen (with accurate width and height). I tried to set it as popupView.center.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.midX in init method, but no luck

Comment: also tried to set the frame in showPopup method as   popupView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 100) but its initialize on the top left corner no matter which numbers I put in frame...

Comment: @artexhibit - please see my update

Comment: thank you, Shawn! Got it. Everything works as I want!